# Jinja2 autoescape

Tags: python, escaping, jinja2

Autoescape is set to false globally. Is there a way to tell Jinja2 to escape a specific template?

The {% autoescape false %} block apparently only works for disabling autoescape in templates if the global settings is set to true and not the other way around.

Comment: If you create two specific environnements (one with the autoescape=True, the other =False) and then use the appropriate one when you render a specific template?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Jinja2 are you using? Is it used on a Flask/Django context or something else?
I tested with Flask==1.1.1 and Jinja2==2.10.1 and what I observed is that `autoescape` is enabled by default when using `render_template`.